# How to find the min and max value of one column based on condition in another column

Tags: pandas

I am trying to find the min and max 'Age' based on values that had Infection_Yes==1

Here is what I am looking at:

```
new_df.loc[new_df['Infection_Yes'] == 1]
```

[image: ![Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)]

```
Age SEX DIABETES    bmi SMOKE   DPRALBUM    Readmission Infection   bmi_cat albumin_cat ... age_cat_lt65    SEX_female  SEX_male    Readmission_No  Readmission_Yes Infection_Yes   Infection_no    Optimized_No    Optimized_Unknown   Optimized_Yes
410 68.0    male    NON-INSULIN 25.01   No  NaN Yes Yes lt40    0   ... 1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
724 54.0    male    NO  34.97   No  13.0    Yes Yes lt40    gt3.5   ... 1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1
736 69.0    female  NO  25.98   No  16.0    No  Yes lt40    gt3.5   ... 1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1
1228    68.0    male    NO  22.86   Yes 12.0    No  Yes lt40    gt3.5   ... 1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0
1297    75.0    female  NO  NaN No  NaN Yes Yes 0   0   ... 0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
5 rows × 37 columns
```

I am wanting to find the max and min age (basically just the range of ages of those who have Infection_Yes==1)

Comment: Could you please post samples/your df in form of text in your question, by which its easy for us to test solutions, thank you.

Comment: new_df.loc[new_df['Infection_Yes'] == 1]['Age'].min() and the same with max

Comment: Thank you, that did it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

next time please add sample df.

```
# import pandas
import pandas as pd

# sample df
d = {'Infection': ['Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y','N'],'Age': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# min max age if Infection == Y
print(df[df['Infection']=='Y']['Age'].min())
print(df[df['Infection']=='Y']['Age'].max())
```

If I missed the point of your question or you need me to clarify anything let me know.
Good luck!

Comment: That did the trick, was just what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: @dwool remember you can mark an answer as accepted. It gives the responder extra points for answering your question (;

Comment: @ArturoSbr oh sorry, I did not know that!